# Buttons only affecting every other div instead of every single div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am trying to create a "library" where you can add books by yourself and they also get a "remove" button that removes the book and a "change status" button that changes the status of the book has been read or not.

Everything works fine except the "change status" button, which only lets the user change the status of every other book. for example if you add 4 books you would only be able to change book 2 and 4, if you add 5 books you can only change books 1,3,5 instead of working for all of them.

```js
const myLibrary = [];

function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
}

// Prototype functions
Book.prototype.info = function() {
  return `${this.title} by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages, ${this.read}`;
};

Book.prototype.changeStatus = function() {
  if ((this.read) == 'Already read') {
    this.read = 'Haven\'t read yet';
  } else if ((this.read) == 'Haven\'t read yet') {
    this.read = 'Already read';
  }
}

// Add a new book to the array
function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read) {
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read);
  myLibrary.push(newBook);
}

// Examples
addBookToLibrary('Title', 'Author', 251, 'Already read');
addBookToLibrary('The book', 'John Smith', 511, 'Already read');
addBookToLibrary('Rich quick', 'Robert', 2541, 'Haven\'t read yet');
addBookToLibrary('How to code', 'Odin', 221, 'Already read');

const books = document.querySelector('.books');

// Display examples for testing
for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
  console.log(myLibrary[i].info());
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  books.appendChild(container);
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = myLibrary[i].info();
  container.appendChild(div);
}


// Display submitted books
function displayBooks() {
  const index = myLibrary.length - 1;
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.classList.add('bookContainer');
  container.setAttribute('data-', `${index}`);
  books.appendChild(container);
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('aBook');
  div.setAttribute('data-', `${index}`);
  div.textContent = myLibrary[index].info();
  container.appendChild(div);
  const btn1 = document.createElement('button');
  btn1.classList.add('remover');
  btn1.setAttribute('data-', `${index}`);
  btn1.textContent = 'Remove';
  container.appendChild(btn1);
  createRemover();
  const btn2 = document.createElement('button');
  btn2.classList.add('changer');
  btn2.setAttribute('data-', `${index}`);
  btn2.textContent = 'Change Status';
  container.appendChild(btn2);
  createChanger();
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.style.display = "none"

// Event handler for new book button
function toggleFormOn() {
  form.style.display = "block"
}

// Event handler for submit form button
function toggleFormOff(event) {
  const createBook = [];
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  const select = document.querySelector('select');
  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    console.log(input.value);
    createBook.push(input.value);
    input.value = '';
  })
  console.log(select.value);
  createBook.push(select.value);

  form.style.display = "none";

  console.log(createBook);
  addBookToLibrary(...createBook)

  for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    console.log(myLibrary[i].info());
  }

  displayBooks();
  event.preventDefault();
}


// Basic Event listeners
const newBtn = document.querySelector('#newBtn');
newBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFormOn);

const subBtn = document.querySelector('#sub');
subBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFormOff);

// Event listening and handling
function createRemover() {
  const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.remover');
  removeBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      const placement = button.getAttribute('data-');
      const bookDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.bookContainer');
      bookDiv.forEach((div) => {
        if (div.firstElementChild.textContent == (myLibrary[placement].info())) {
          div.remove();
        }
      })
    })
  })
}

function createChanger() {
  const changeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.changer');
  changeBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      const placement = button.getAttribute('data-');
      const bookDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.bookContainer');
      bookDiv.forEach((div) => {
        if (div.firstElementChild.textContent == (myLibrary[placement].info())) {
          myLibrary[placement].changeStatus();
          div.firstElementChild.textContent = myLibrary[placement].info();
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="books">

</div>
<button id="newBtn">NEW BOOK</button>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="bookTitle">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="bookTitle" name="bookTitle">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="bookAuthor">Author</label>
      <input type="text" id="bookAuthor" name="bookAuthor">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="bookPages">Pages</label>
      <input type="text" id="bookPages" name="bookPages">
    </li>
    <li id="heading">Did you read it?</li>
    <li>
      <select name="bookRead" id="bookRead">
        <option value="Already read">Read</option>
        <option value="Haven't read yet">Didn't read</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li class="btn">
      <button type="submit" id="sub">Submit</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I tried changing a lot of stuff: tweaking the html structure, modifying the `createChanger()` and also `displayBooks()`. Nothing seems to work since I can't identify the issue that is causing it to only change every other book and not every single book.

Comment: Two straightforward options would be to assign the handler at book creation time with a closure over the individual book (no need to get the index) or to implement event delegation with a single handler.

Comment: You could probably avoid looping through all of the buttons in your `changer(...)` function, by passing an argument, and using `document.querySelector(<arg>)` to attach the handler. Also, your data attributes seem to be broken - instead of `data-<something>="..."`, they are `data-="..."`. Also #2, your events for every other `change` button are working, it's just that there are **two** of them attached - check Firefox element inspector, and click on the `<event>` next to your 2nd, 4th, etc button.